# visual studio 2010 setup project - uninstall custom action

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

During install, I'm passing some CustomActionData to CustomAction.

Is that data stored somehow? I need to use some of the data during uninstall in uninstall custom action.

I can't resend this data because user might not be using the msi file to uninstall but go to add / remove programs.

I need somehow in uninstall custom action to retrieve data that was already sent during install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the usual approach:

- save the information you need in an installer property
- use that property as a registry entry value
- create a search (in Launch Conditions Editor) which reads this registry entry
- the search property can be used during uninstall

Basically, you save the information during install and read it through a search during uninstall.